# Should I imagine B-Trees to be growing/expanding upwards or downwards?

Tags: data-structures, b-tree

When being taught B-Trees, I always saw the middle number of a filled node go upwards rather than the rest of the nodes with keys go downwards. So I was just wondering in my head if I should imagine the tree growing up or down.

I expect the tree to be actually going down but it always visually seems to go up.

Answer (score 0):

It is of course a matter of imagination, but for B-trees it is true that the only way a it can increase its height, is by splitting the root node and creating a new level for the new root that has the split nodes as its children.

So indeed, a B-tree gets its levels at the root side, not at the side of the leaves. If we imagine the root to be at the top, then indeed a B-tree grows upwards (and also sideways of course).

Comment: Thank you. If I were to implement the insert for a b-tree if I were at a point where a new level upwards had to be made would I make the node as a parent then or would the new upward level be treated as the old node and make the split nodes now children of the new level?

Comment: It is a free choice, but it will be easier to do the split by moving half of its keys and links to a new node that will become its sibling, and create a new root node that has the median key and these two nodes as children. So one of the children could be considered "the original" node.